# "Instance member cannot be used on type" error in lazy property

Tags: arrays, swift

[image: I wonder this error]

Please help me solve this problem or tell me the right way to declaring this property.

```
// MARK: Properties
var expensiveItems = [Item]()
var cheapItems = [Item]()

lazy var allItems: [[Item]] = {
    return [cheapItems, expensiveItems]
}()
```

Comment: why do you have a `return` in a variable?

Comment: @Rana he's assigning the result of a closure to his lazily loaded property, which is perfectly valid in Swift. [See here for more info](http://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/).

Comment: @originaluser2 thanks, I've never seen that before.

Comment: @originaluser2 Thank you for you help ,  My negligence

Answer (score 4):

Because you're assigning the result of a closure to your lazily loaded property - you need to follow the closure rules. One of those rules is that if you're referring to `self` - you must do it explicitly. <sub>(although this isn't applicable for `@noescape` closures – but you can't use them here anyway)</sub>

This is simply so that you acknowledge that you're capturing and retaining `self`, but seeing as it's a lazily loaded property it shouldn't cause a retain cycle, as it is only called once and it's result is then assigned to the property.

Therefore you need to use `self.cheapItems` and `self.expensiveItems`.

```
// MARK: Properties
var expensiveItems = [Item]()
var cheapItems = [Item]()

lazy var allItems: [[Item]] = {
    return [self.cheapItems, self.expensiveItems]
}()
```