# Assigning 'class variable' to variable inside 'lazy var'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview, lazy-initialization

I am trying to understand the logic of draggable collection view cells. It works with dummy data however, I couldn't figure out how to make it work with real data.

*I couldn't know what title to give to the question, please feel free to edit/improve it*

If I use this approach with a dummy array items and call the function

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, KDRearrangeableCollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource { 

lazy var data : [[String]] = {

    var array = [[String]]()

    let images = [
        "1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"
    ]

    if array.count == 0 {

        var index = 0
        var section = 0

        for image in images {
            if array.count <= section {
                array.append([String]())
            }
            array[section].append(image)

            index += 1
        }
    }
    return array
}()

func moveDataItem(fromIndexPath : NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let name = self.data[fromIndexPath.section][fromIndexPath.item]
    self.data[fromIndexPath.section].removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.item)
    self.data[toIndexPath.section].insert(name, atIndex: toIndexPath.item)

    print(self.data) 
}
```

At this point `print(self.data)` prints the new order of the array items after dragging/rearranging.

Example `print(self.data`) log:
     *`[["2.jpg", "1.jpg", "3.jpg"]]`*

---

Now I have my real data as and it gets appended by items after fetching from database..

```
var realImages = [NSURL]()

// I tried assigning `images` array inside `lazy var data` but received error: 

lazy var data : [[String]] = { 
    var array = [[String]]()
    let images = realImages    // error here
            ...
```

> Instance member realImages cannot be used on type TableViewController

What is the proper way of using my real array in that case?

---

*([This explanation](http://blog.karmadust.com/drag-and-rearrange-uicollectionviews-through-layouts/) and [its Git repo](https://github.com/mmick66/KDRearrangeableCollectionViewFlowLayout) was great for understanding it). I simplified it even further with dummy data but I couldn't understand the logic of 'lazy var' and regular 'var' and how to make it work in this scenario*

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Instance member cannot be used on type" error in lazy property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990637/i-want-put-an-array-to-an-array-but-why-do-i-get-this-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use self explicitly like `let images = self.realImages`.

```
lazy var data : [[String]] = { [unonwed self] in
    var array = [[String]]()
    let images = self.realImages    // error gone :)
```

(Note that we had to say [unowned self] in here to prevent a [strong reference cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_61))

Comment: You actually don't need to use `unowned` or `weak` on `self` here. Lazy variables don't generate strong reference cycles as they're only created once.  Once they are called, the result of the closure is stored, not the closure itself – therefore no strong reference cycle. Even if you don't call them, they are smart enough not to hold a strong reference to `self` – you can test this in a playground.